# Renaming all files in folder in numeric order

Tags: c#, rename

i know this seems pretty simple and i know theres other questions asking this but i just need to know what im personally doing wrong and why it doesnt work because it should.

```
        int ImageCounter = 1;

        foreach (var Image in ImageFilePaths)
        {
            {
               // Console.WriteLine(Image);
               // Console.WriteLine(RenameFolderPath + @"\" + ImageCounter + ".jpeg");
                    File.Move(Image, RenameFolderPath + @"\" + ImageCounter + ".jpeg");
                   ImageCounter++;
            }
        }
```

So theres about 150 images in a folder and after running this, im left with 11, 10 of which are numbered 1-10 and the 11th is left with its original name.
if i print (image) it will print about 150 of the original names, if i print the 2nd writeline, it will print the exact same but "1 - about 150" instead of the original name. so theres no problems there, it must be with the file.move but i cannot see anything wrong

Comment: im not getting any errors and its not in a try statment, what other code would u like? everything around it works because it 100% scrolls through every file

Comment: Your going to have to post more code - we have no idea what ImageFilePaths is - for instance, if it is an IEnumerable of a folder listing, its not fully evaluated, therefore you Move will interfere with the output of the ForEach.

Comment: `            string[] ImageFilePaths = new string[] { };
            string RenameFolderPath = AppDataPath + @"\Graphics\BackupSorting\" + RootFolderName + @"\0-1";
            ImageFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(RenameFolderPath);`

Comment: sorry i dont know how to write code in a comment but thats the variables, thats everything in the function apart from the Rootfoldername which is just "s" that i bring in

Comment: There's "\0-1" at the end of your RenameFolderPath, is the last 1 normal ? That might be the cause.

Comment: Yes the folder is called \0-1, then when moving files i made sure to put another \ after it so they went inside it

Comment: thats weird, i moved the function to a button click so i could watch it do it and its working now, its c# because its part of a bigger project and i know c# better than other langs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but this works for me:

```
void Main()
{
    MoveFiles(@"c:\Temp\MoveTest", @"C:\Temp\MoveTest1");
}

public void MoveFiles(string fromDir, string toDir)
{
    int ImageCounter = 1;

    // Take a snapshot of the file system.
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(fromDir);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> ImageFilePaths = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); 

    foreach (var Image in ImageFilePaths)
    {
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Image);
            Console.WriteLine(toDir + @"\" + ImageCounter + ".jpeg");
            File.Move(Image.FullName, toDir + @"\" + ImageCounter + ".jpeg");
            ImageCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```